# python: how to use win32api.PostMessage

Tags: python, pywin32

I use python to send a key to an application.

I use `win32gui`:

`hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None,"busmaster")` returns 5441816

`hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None,"busmaster")` returns 3606522

But `win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord('a'), 0)` returns 0

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Find method send_chars(...) in pywinauto. We already use it right way. But some things depend on application.

Answer (score 0):

Sending keys to active window is much easier with this approach:

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.SendKeys('abc')
shell.SendKeys('^v')  # Ctrl+V
shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')  # Enter key
```

and to make a window active you need

```
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I must work in background.. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513/)